# ¿Porque me sale este error en java 'else' without 'if'?

Tags: java

```
package ejercicio;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Ejercicio 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int ex;
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        float numero1 , volumen;
        do{
        try
        {
        ex=0;

        System.out.println("Digite el radio:");
        numero1= entrada.nextInt();

        if (numero1<=5000)
        {

            if (numero1>0)
            {
                {volumen=(float) ((4*Math.PI*Math.pow(numero1, 3))/((3))-(8*Math.pow(numero1, 3)/(3*Math.sqrt(3))));
                System.out.println("El volumen residual es : "+ volumen);
            }
            else    // Aquí me da el error de 'else' without 'if'
                {
                        System.out.println("El numero: " +numero1+ "es demasiado pequeño, digite un numero mayor a 0");
                        ex=1;
                        entrada.nextLine();
                }
            }

            else
            {
            System.out.println("El numero:" +numero1 +"es demasiado grande, digite un numero menor a 5000");
            ex=1;
            entrada.nextLine();
            }
        }


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("No se admiten caracteres, por favor digite un numero:");
            ex=1;
            entrada.nextLine();
        }

        }while (ex !=0);


    }
}
```

Comment: Trata de tabular bien (o utiliza el formateo automático de tu IDE) y enseguida verás el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu codigo correjido es el siguiente

```
package ejercicio;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Ejercicio {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ex;
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        float numero1, volumen;
        do {
            try {
                ex = 0;

                System.out.println("Digite el radio:");
                numero1 = entrada.nextInt();

                if (numero1 <= 5000) {
                    if (numero1 > 0) {
                        {
                            volumen = (float)((4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(numero1, 3)) / ((3)) - (8 * Math.pow(numero1, 3) / (3 * Math.sqrt(3))));
                            System.out.println("El volumen residual es : " + volumen);
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("El numero: " + numero1 + "es demasiado pequeño, digite un numero mayor a 0");
                            ex = 1;
                            entrada.nextLine();
                        }
                    }
                } //Este if no estaba cerrando bien, contenia al else dentro
                else {
                    System.out.println("El numero:" + numero1 + "es demasiado grande, digite un numero menor a 5000");
                    ex = 1;
                    entrada.nextLine();

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("No se admiten caracteres, por favor digite un numero:");
                ex = 1;
                entrada.nextLine();
            }

        } while (ex != 0);
    }
}
```

**El problema estaba en que estabas cerrando el primer IF con su ELSE dentro**

Comment: Muchas gracias, perdón por esa molestia.

Comment: No hay problema! suerte :D

Comment: @LcsGrz Gracias, Tu respuesta me fue de gran ayuda, soy nuevo en este lenguaje.